# Passport Facebook Always Redirect

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, callback

First of all I'd like to thank every people who would read my post

Here the problem : 
I use passport facebook auth from jaredhanson but once I finally managed to login and now each time I go to /auth/facebook (even on my smartphone) it always redirect to /auth/facebook/callback?code=XYC... whereas it should redirect to the Facebook login page each time..
Here is my code :

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(
  {
    clientID: config.facebook.oauth.clientId,
    clientSecret: config.facebook.oauth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebook.oauth.callbackURL,
    profileFields: config.facebook.oauth.profileFields,
  },
  ((accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    User.findOrCreateFacebook(profile, (err, user) => {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }),
));
router.get('', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
router.get(
  '/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/facebook',
  }), (req, res) => {
    const profile = {
      id: req.user._id, //eslint-disable-line
      firstname: req.user.FName,
      lastname: req.user.LName,
      email: req.user.email,
      profilPic: req.user.photoProfil,
    };
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      token: signToken(profile),
    });
  },
);
UserSchema.statics.findOrCreateFacebook = function findOrCreateFacebook(profile, callback) {
  const user = new this();
  this.findOne({ facebookId: profile.id }, (err, result) => {
    // Be careful of the case duplicate mail
    if (!result) {
      user.email = profile._json.email;
      user.facebookId = profile._json.id;
      user.LName = profile._json.last_name;
      user.gender = profile._json.gender;
      user.FName = profile._json.first_name;
      user.photoProfil = profile.photos.length > 0 ? profile.photos[0].value : null;
      user.password = 'facebook'; // useless thing..
      user.save((error) => {
        callback(error, user);
      });
    } else {
      callback(err, result);
    }
  });
};
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```

Honestly i'm getting crazy :(

Comment: If you already logged in to this app before and granted it all the permissions it asks for, then redirecting right back from the login dialog URL without actually bothering the user again is what is supposed to happen … When your app’s callback URL is requested with a code parameter, then it is your app’s job to now make the API request to exchange that code for a token.

Comment: Yes I got it but in fact the code is already exchanged by the passport facebook strategy no ?
Do you have an idea how can I fix the problem ?